# Kinect v2 Connectivity Issue

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, kinect-interaction

I am Trying to Connect/Configure Kinect v2. on my Laptop. I have HP DV6 with Dual Graphics, Intel 3000 and AMD Radeon 6700 2GB dedicated. But after installing Kinect SDK, When i Run Kinect Configuration Verifier, It Gives me 2 errors. 
1- No DirectX 11 Capable GPU detected.
2- No Depth Frames Recieved from Kinect.

My System has DirectX 11 installed. I have attached the DirectX Diagnostic and Control Panel Screenshots Links below.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/583253
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/583249

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

**Disable Power saver** in Power Options and:

- **Update** **Catalyst Control Center** (CCC) andr **Drivers**
- run CCC
  (right click on desktop background and select CCC ora right click on CCC icon in system tray or search "Catalyst Control in start menu)
- on left side of CCC click on "Game" Cateogry and select "3D Application Settings".
- Click the "**Add**" options and select the .exe that utilize Kinect (for example: **KinectV2ConfigurationVerifier.exe**, your application.exe )
- go to Graphics -> PowerPlay
- select **Enable PowerPlay** and set **Plugged and Battery to Maximum Performance**
- go to Graphics->3D
- **set** for **Optimal Performance** and apply
- if your CCC has **Switchable Graphics tab**, **add** there all **.exe** that utilize Kinect and **set Hight Performance**.
- **restart** your laptop

Comment: I have done this.. But Still No Luck.
See the screen shot : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/583291

Comment: I updated the answer, let me know if this resolve your issue with discrete GPU

Answer (score 0):

[**Solved**] I upgraded the AMD Radeon Drivers and USB Host Controller. Then I added my exe into Switchable Graphics tab. and Enabled Maximize Performance. My issue is resolved. Thanks